# Interpolation by a continuously differentiable function

Tags: sequences-and-series, banach-spaces, interpolation

Let $Y$ be an open convex subset of a Banach space and let $\{y_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset Y$ be a sequence. Is there a continuously differentiable function $f:\mathbb R \to Y$ such that $f(k)=y_k,k=1,2,...$?

Comment: Can't you just take $f(x) = p(x-k) \cdot y_k$ for $x \in [k-1/2,k+1/2]$, where $p$ is a polynomial with $p(0)=1$ and such that p has zeros of order 2 at $\pm 1/2$? In other words, $p(x) = c (x-1/2)^2(x+1/2)^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! As a modification of you idea, probably I should consider $f(t)=y_k+p(t-k)(y_{k+1}-y_k), t \in [k,k+1]$, where $p(t)=10t^3-15t^4+6t^5$. Since $p(0)=p'(0)=p''(0)=p'(1)=p''(1)=0$, $p(1)=1$, and $p([0,1])=[0,1]$, we are done.

Comment: Oh, yes, you want to stay inside the convex set. Somehow overread that part.